# SQL Unpivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am facing problem on unpivot sql statement, below is the table how its look like:

```
ID  A0001       A0002      A0003
==  =========== ========== ==========
S1  100         200        300 
S2  321         451        234
S3  0           111        222
```

I want to pivot A0001,A0002 and A0003. Create 3 more column for HEADER,SEQUENCE AND DATA.
Below is my expected table to become like this:

```
ID  HEADER      SEQUENCE     DATA
==  ==========  ===========  =======
S1  A0001       1            100 
S1  A0001       2            200
S1  A0001       3            300
S2  A0002       1            321
S2  A0002       2            451
S2  A0002       3            234
S3  A0003       1            111
S3  A0003       2            222
```

Below is the sql statement I have try:

```
SELECT ID,DATA FROM
(SELECT ID,A0001,A0002,A0003 FROM STG.TABLE_A)
UNPIVOT
(DATA FOR B IN (A0001,A0002,A0003)) C
```

The SQL I write only allow to show the data after pivot, for HEADER and SEQUENCE field I have no idea how to write

Secondly, I would also like to filter out if any pivot column is zero will be filter out. 
Example, ID = S3, A0001 is 0,therefore filter the zero and only get other fields which is greater than zero

Comment: It would be useful if you could show us what you have tried so far and what problems you have.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Can you confirm that the Header column has the correct values?

Comment: also what version of SQL server are you using? you can use the pivot and unpivot functions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I am using mysql 2008 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this condition after appling unpivot as below -

```
SELECT ID, DATA, header
  FROM (SELECT ID, A0001, A0002, A0003 FROM STG.TABLE_A) 
        UNPIVOT(DATA FOR header IN (A0001, A0002, A0003)) C
 where data <> 0
```

You can either use the `unvipot` function or you can simply use `union` also in this case as below -

```
   select id, header, sequence, data
    from (select @i := if(@lastid != id, 1, $i + 1) as sequence,
           @lastid := id,
           id,
           header,
           data
      from (

            select ID, 'A0001' as Header, A0001 as DATA
              from your_table_name
             where A0001 <> 0
            union all
            select ID, 'A0002' as Header, A0002 as DATA
              from your_table_name
             where A0002 <> 0
            union all
            select ID, 'A0003' as Header, A0003 as DATA
              from your_table_name
             where A0003 <> 0
            )t_1
            ORDER BY ID, DATA
    ) t_2
```

Comment: The latter query doesn't need the sequence generator (which could prove to be very unreliable) according to the OP's example.

Comment: In Question this sequence is one column and I thought that it would be helpful to provide logic to show sequence in mysql query on groups.

Comment: @symcbean Please tell why sequence generation is unreliable.. whether mysql query will give incorrect result if we add sequence generation logic also in the query.

Comment: @pratikgarg You're missing an `from (...)t_1 ORDER BY ID, DATA` in there. And there is no `UNPIVOT()` in MySQL. Apart from that your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks @tombom for highlighting the `unpivot` part..
Actually I am working on oracle database and hence I thought in mysql also unpivot option is available.. since Arzozeus tried on this command so I thought that this command is valid and available in Mysql also.. but afterwards I searched and got that this is not valid syntax in Mysql.. Thanks for updating my knowledge on mysql also ..

Comment: Still the `ORDER BY` is missing, without it it really is unreliable, like symcbean mentioned.

Comment: @tombom In Oracle database if you have union clause then it will show first query result in top then second and then so on.. 
I read and mysql also work like this only.
as we are selecting A0001 column and then A0002 and then A0003 then it should give result as per desired output..
i have added order by in each union query .. I hope these ordering you were talking about.

Comment: No, it's not :) Let me fix it for you. (and +1)