# Return constant literal from select query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, case

```
SELECT (
 CASE  
   WHEN t.status_id = 13 THEN 1
   WHEN t.status_id = 14 THEN 2 
 END)
FROM tea t WHERE t.id =13
```

Above query is working. But what I need is to return a string instead of number.

```
SELECT (
 CASE  
   WHEN t.status_id = 13 THEN CLOSE
   WHEN t.status_id = 14 THEN OPEN
 END)
FROM tea t WHERE t.id =13
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS), string literals/constants need to be enclose in single quotes: `then 'CLOSE'` - but a lookup table might be a better solution. Also: putting the case between parentheses ( `(case ... end) `) is totally useless.

Comment: Putting 'CLOSE' did not work.

Comment: Sorry worked it. I was trying the same. But now It worked

Answer (score 0):

Like [@a_horse told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405175/return-constant-literal-from-select-query-in-postgresql#comment58511666_35405175), but I advise to add an explicit type cast to be clear and avoid any possible complication:

```
SELECT CASE t.status_id              -- "switched" case
          WHEN 13 THEN text 'CLOSE'  -- explicit cast (text would be default)
          WHEN 14 THEN      'OPEN'   -- later CASE terms are coerced to same type
                                     -- so cast is optional
       END AS status                 -- add a column alias.
FROM   tea t
WHERE  t.id = 13;
```

- [Postgres data type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871)
- [How to get the column name of the result of a least function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567600/how-to-get-the-column-name-of-the-result-of-a-least-function/27570354#27570354)