# pivot & unpivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I've been stuck on this for sometime now.
I have a Healthcare_WorldBank.dbo.wb_new table with
country_name (varchar), country_code (varchar), series_code (varchar), yr_2015 (float), yr_2016 (float), yr_2017 (float).
I have been trying to unpivot the table to create a table with
country_name, country_code, year (will be 2015, 2016, 2017), the series_code spread out as extra columns with the corresponding values of yr_2015, yr_2016, yr_2017

This is the table I have

| country_name | country_code | series_code | yr_2015 | yr_2016 | yr_2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | DZA | CHE | 6.98 | 6.61 | 6.28 |
| Algeria | DZA | CAPHE | 2.61 | 2.71 | 2.79 |
| Algeria | DZA | CHE_CAP | 2.91 | 2.74 | 2.62 |
| Algeria | DZA | CHE_CAP_PPP | 5.73 | 5.56 | 6.13 |

This is the table I am trying to recreate

| country_name | country_code | year | CHE | CAPHE | CHE_CAP | CHE_CAP_PPP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | DZA | 2015 | 6.98 | 2.61 | 2.91 | 5.73 |
| Algeria | DZA | 2016 | 6.61 | 2.71 | 2.74 | 5.56 |
| Algeria | DZA | 2017 | 6.28 | 2.79 | 2.62 | 6.13 |

I have tried union all but the values don't match up.

Comment: As a side note, I suspect that the `float` data type is *not* the correct choice of data for your `yr_` columns. Base 2 values aren't great at storing not integer base 10 values.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361150/sql-unpivot-table

Comment: https://www.righto.com/2012/11/obama-on-sorting-1m-integers-bubble.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpivot years, then pivot series codes:

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9noRvWWQ)

```
select country_name, country_code, substring(yr, 4, 4) as yr, 
       [CHE], [CAPHE], [CHE_CAP], [CHE_CAP_PPP]  
from (
  select country_name, country_code, series_code, val, yr from wb_new
  unpivot (val for yr in (yr_2015, yr_2016, yr_2017)) as unpvt ) u
pivot ( max(val) 
  for series_code in ([CHE], [CAPHE], [CHE_CAP], [CHE_CAP_PPP])) pvt;
```